# useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I want to implement `componentDidMount` in hooks that I want to do something for the first rendering **ONLY**, so in the `useEffect`, I set the dependency array as empty, but eslint has the warning that dependency is missing.
how to solve it?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Child = ({ age }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("simulate componentDidMount, age:", age);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('simulate componentDidUpdate, age:', age)
  }, [age])

  return <div>age: {age}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const handleOnClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setAge(a => a + 1);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child age={age} />
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>INCREASE AGE</button>
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the first render in a ref and do what you need to do when `isFirstRender.current` is true, this way you don't need to add anything but `age` to your effect and can combine cDM and cDU together, storing the lifecycle in state doesn't make sense to me.

```js
const Child = ({ age }) => {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
      console.log("simulate componentDidMount, age:", age);
      return
    }
    console.log('simulate componentDidUpdate, age:', age);
  }, [age]);

  return <div>age: {age}</div>;
};
```

You can also extract it into a custom hook if you want to reuse it

```js
const useIsFirstRender = () => {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    isFirstRender.current = false;
  }, []);

  return isFirstRender.current;
};

const Child = ({ age }) => {
  const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender) {
      console.log("simulate componentDidMount, age:", age);
      return;
    }
    console.log('simulate componentDidUpdate, age:', age)
  }, [age, isFirstRender]);

  return <div>age: {age}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It says the dependency is missing because you do use `age` inside your `useEffect`, even if it's just for printing it out, so `eslint` probably believes you should add `age` do the dependency list.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("simulate componentDidMount, age:", age); //age is being used here
  }, []);
```

Comment: if I add `age` into dependency, later when `age` is updated, the function inside `useEffect` would be invoked again. I want to implement something similar to `componentDidMount` which is invoked only once

Comment: I understand, but if you want to print out age in that useEffect while still keeping the componentDidMount, you'll have to ignore the warning.

Comment: do you reckon if it is better to have a local state to record if it is first rendering?

Comment: @HuanLi - ***better to have local state to record first rendering***, no in my opinion too complicated. You know the purpose of your code better than eslint, just suppress the warning. I use `}, []); // eslint-disable-line` all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this if you don't want to disable eslint:

```
const [component_mounted, set_component_mounted] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    if(!component_mounted) {
      // Use age here
      set_component_mounted(true)
    }
  }, [age, component_mounted, set_component_mounted])
```

Comment: One point for correct code, but how noisy is that? (compared to a linting comment)

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't care how you use the state.  So printing the age has no difference from putting the age in some logic computing. Eslint did right.

Comment: You don't get my point. I would like to implement `componentDidMount` without eslint warning